# Sending POST request to a WebService from Excel

Tags: excel, web-services

We have a scenario that requires us to send POST requests from Excel to a Web Service.

**Sample request to API:**
http://localhost/api/createticket?name=mark&rowNumber=65

The parameters (name & rowNumber) should be taken from Excel cells.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: That looks like GET, not POST

Comment: What have you tried/thought about using so far? If the parameters are going to vary then you are probably looking at using some VBA. What do you expect to get back in response to your request? And what, if anything, are you going to do with that response back in Excel?

Comment: @DMM - hoping not to use VBA & instead use an inbuilt function in Excel if that exists. 

No response will be posted back in Excel (except possible to notify user "Request sent to WebService".) The WebService will handle the request/post and send an email notification ("your ticket has been created successfully & the workflow has been initiated") to the user who has requested it.

Comment: @Mark - Excel's in-built webby features are mainly intended to pull data into Excel for analysis purposes, so I still think you will probably need to use VBA (searching for XMLHTTP would be  a reasonable starting point). Presumably, your web service will identify if the same request has been issued issued twice if you not planning to manage this aspect from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Typical examples involve VBA script (Alt+F11 in Excel to edit):

```
Dim oX as Object
Set oX = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") ' there are many versions of this object, look around
Dim URL = "http://your.server.url/webservice/"
oHttp.Open "POST", URL, False
oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Dim data As String ' this looks like querystring but is actually a POST body
data = data & "&SITE=LM"
data = data & "&NSP=999"
oHttp.send (data)
Dim response = oHttp.responseText
MsgBox response
```

Unfortunately the ActiveX function *CreateObject* is failing on my work machine and I expect it to be increasingly blocked in many environments.

A quick and **simple alternative is the WEBSERVICE function**, but it seems to only allow GET requests without body and authentication:

```
=WEBSERVICE("http://mywebservice.com/serviceEndpoint?searchString=Excel")
```

More: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/webservice-function-0546a35a-ecc6-4739-aed7-c0b7ce1562c4